# Need help to resolve CPU usage (Breached to 100%) of SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Last couple of days our sql server cpu usage reached to (Production server)100 %. We have 200 databases in server. Can someone help how to find which database and which table,stored procedure consuming time during particular time of cpu usage?

Comment: How do you know it's `SQL` causing these problems and not a process outside of it? Here's a great [**read**](http://logicalread.solarwinds.com/troubleshoot-high-cpu-sql-server-pd01/#.WCvhr7NMHk9) from Pinal Dave about this issue.

Comment: Thanks for  reply. I was monitoring the performance in Windows Task Manager., CPU Usage reaching 100%. We have Server alert mail during cpu breached the usage. Is there query to find table, SPs and database name between from and to time?

Comment: `select * from master..sysprocesses
where status = 'runnable' --comment this out
order by CPU
desc` this detects high cpu connections... SQL Profiler can be good in this case as well...

Comment: This looks not helpful Zaggler, it was not giving expected output of my previous question. :(

Comment: If not helpful then good luck. There's tools available for these kinds of things, again it can be many things....

Comment: Question should be migrated to http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions, you have better chance there.

Comment: Just use the activity monitor in SSMS, look at the "Recent Expensive Queries" section, sort results by CPU etc. There is also a "Processes" section you might want to look at.

Comment: Just a hint, if you have 200 databases, you should also have few DBAs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code helped me to get expected result.

```
SELECT TOP 10 DBName = DB_NAME(qt.dbid),o.Name,qt.text,
SUBSTRING(qt.TEXT, (qs.statement_start_offset/2)+1,
((CASE qs.statement_end_offset
WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(qt.TEXT)
ELSE qs.statement_end_offset
END - qs.statement_start_offset)/2)+1),
qs.execution_count,
qs.total_logical_reads, qs.last_logical_reads,
qs.total_logical_writes, qs.last_logical_writes,
qs.total_worker_time,
qs.last_worker_time,
qs.total_elapsed_time/1000000 total_elapsed_time_in_S,
qs.last_elapsed_time/1000000 last_elapsed_time_in_S,
qs.last_execution_time,
qp.query_plan,qs.sql_handle 
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) qt
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) qp
LEFT JOIN sys.objects o on o.object_id = qt.objectid 
--ORDER BY qs.total_logical_reads DESC -- logical reads
-- ORDER BY qs.total_logical_writes DESC -- logical writes
WHERE qs.last_execution_time>= 'Your from date' 
AND qs.last_execution_time<='Your from date'
ORDER BY qs.last_worker_time DESC -- CPU time
```

Comment: Plan cache doesn't tell you `...consuming time during particular time of cpu usage`. It only shows plans that are cached right now, and what the cpu / io usage of them has been.